# Custom icons for my add-on doesn't work!

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am making custom icons for my Blender add-on. I read the [bpy.utils.previews.ImagePreviewCollection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.previews.html#bpy.utils.previews.ImagePreviewCollection) already. I tried code and set the `__file__` to `bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath` it works very well.

But, when I add the codes to my add-on file, it doesn't show the icon. Here is the code:

```py
#Add-on info
bl_info = {
    "name": "Shader",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Toolbar > Shader",
    "description": "Add shaders to your object",
    "category": "3D View",
}



import os
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty
from bpy.types import Panel



# Main panel for adding colour to object
class ShaderPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Shader"
    bl_idname = "ShaderPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Shader'
    
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pcoll = preview_collections["main"]
        row = layout.row()
        my_icon = pcoll["my_icon"]
        your_icon = pcoll["your_icon"]
        
        row.operator("render.render", icon_value=your_icon.icon_id)
        row.operator("render.render", icon_value=my_icon.icon_id)
        
        

classes = [ShaderPanel]

preview_collections = {}


def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        EnumProperty,
    )
    
    ############ Custom Icons ############
    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    # path to the folder where the icon is
    # the path is calculated relative to this py file inside the addon folder
    my_icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")

    # load a preview thumbnail of a file and store in the previews collection
    pcoll.load("my_icon", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "icon.png"), 'IMAGE')
    pcoll.load("your_icon", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "icon1.png"), 'IMAGE')

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    #######################################

    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    __file__ = bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath
    register()
```

I did not get error, but it doesn't show icon. Here is what I got:
[image]

Here is the folders and files/images location:

[image]

Please help me, I already read many common questions but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hello ! While it's nice to provide a working code example, could you restrict it to the part that's responsible for drawing the UI so it's easier to pinpoint it ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Gorgious I don't understand what you want me to do. Do you mean there is too many codes on it that uneasy too read?

Comment: Do you know why my code doesn't work, but the code in documentation works?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying it would take me 10 mins to read through all of your addon code to try and find out what is wrong, while if you isolated the part that's responsible for drawing the UI in the panel, that time would be much faster

Comment: @Gorgious Now, I edited. I already put those unrelated codes away and pls see my codes and find what's the problem. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path to resources is wrong:

```
my_icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")
```

See `template ui_previews_custom_icon.py`:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: You need to replace the image path with a real existing one.
> For distributable scripts, it is recommended to place the icons inside
> the addon folder and access it relative to the py script file for
> portability

For this we can use `bpy.utils.user_resource(resource_type, path='', create=False)` [link](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bpy.utils.html?highlight=bpy%20utils%20user_resource#bpy.utils.user_resource)

Script:

```
#Add-on info
bl_info = {
    "name": "Shader",
    "author": "me",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 92, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Toolbar > Shader",
    "description": "Add shaders to your object",
    "category": "3D View",
}

import os
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty
from bpy.types import Panel

# Main panel for adding colour to object
class SHADER_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Shader"
    bl_idname = "SHADER_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Shader'
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pcoll = preview_collections["main"]
        row = layout.row()
        my_icon = pcoll["my_icon"]
        your_icon = pcoll["your_icon"]
        
        row.operator("render.render", icon_value=your_icon.icon_id)
        row.operator("render.render", icon_value=my_icon.icon_id)
        

classes = [SHADER_PT_PANEL]
preview_collections = {}


def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import (
        StringProperty,
        EnumProperty,
    )
    
    ############ Custom Icons ############
    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    # path to the folder where the icon is
    # the path is calculated relative to this py file inside the addon folder
###    my_icons_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons")

    # this path is for installed addons in user_resources ; doesn´t work as script , for script you need a path to your resources
    my_icons_dir = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', path='addons\Shader' , create=False)   # assuming addon folder is called 'Shader'

    # load a preview thumbnail of a file and store in the previews collection
    pcoll.load("my_icon", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "icon.png"), 'IMAGE')              # assuming '*.png' is inside folder 'Shader'
    pcoll.load("your_icon", os.path.join(my_icons_dir, "icon1.png"), 'IMAGE')

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    #######################################

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    __file__ = bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath
    register()
```

Comment: according to your answer, my code should change to `my_icons_dir = bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS', path='Shader Adder\icons' , create=False)` since my path is `\Documents\Scripting\Blender\Shader Adder\icons` but this doesn't work. Please tell me what is the problem, thx

Comment: Another question about your answer, you tell me to see template `ui_previews_custom_icon.py`, but my code is copy from it. You also note that I need to replace the image path with a real existing one, so my code has: `__file__ = bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath` .

Comment: `print(bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS'))` returns the folder where installed (!) user addons are saved in a subfolder called addons. For this `path='addons\Shader Adder\icons'`if addonfolder is _Shader Adder_ and icons in subfolder _icons_.
`bpy.context.space_data.text.filepath` is the path from where a file was loaded into the text editor.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I understand now.